# Polly does not do the retry action

Tags: c#, polly

I have created a simple scenario to test the Polly I might be totally wrong. 
If it does the retry, the retries variable should be 3.

Please take a look at what I have done.Thanks.

```
void Something(int Try)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Try <= 3)
                    throw new InvalidStudentNameException();

            }
            catch
            {

            }

        }
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int retries = 0;
            try
            {
                Something(retries);
                var Result = retries;
                var response = Policy
                    .Handle<InvalidStudentNameException>()
                    .Retry(3, (exception, attempt) =>
                    {
                        retries++;
                    })
                    .Execute
                    (() => Result);

                int reachable = response;
            }
            //catch (InvalidStudentNameException SSSS)
            //{

            //}
            finally
            {
                Response.Write(retries);
            }
        }
```

Retry variable is always Zero. So how ?.

Answer (score 0):

In the posted code your call to `Something(retries)` is not governed by the retry policy. 
 It is a straightforward method call, called when `retries == 0`, and it throws straight away.

For the policy to govern the call to `Something(...)`, you need to execute `Something(...)` in the delegate passed to the `Execute(() => )` method.

The `Button1_Click(...)` method in your example could be modified as follows:

```
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int retries = 0;
            try
            {
                Action doSomething = () => Something(retries); // Creates an `Action` delegate which will be run by the retry policy.
                var response = Policy
                    .Handle<InvalidStudentNameException>()
                    .Retry(3, (exception, attempt) =>
                    {
                        retries++;
                    })
                    .Execute(doSomething); // Runs the action, ie executes Something(...), within the retry policy.

                int reachable = response;
            }
            //catch (InvalidStudentNameException SSSS)
            //{

            //}
            finally
            {
                Response.Write(retries);
            }
        }
```

(I have made minimal changes to the code, just to illustrate the necessary.)

Comment: Thanks. Not only your code works, I did follow another way which is works.